# Fastest way to apply simple function to blocks of memory

Tags: assembly

I have two pairs of files; `A1`,`A2`,`B1`,`B2`; all of identical size. I want a file `C` made up of bytes from the first file in each pair, based on a comparison of the same byte in the corresponding file; in my case, this specific function: `C[i] = (A1[i] < B1[i]) ? A2[i] : B2[i]`. Files are on the order of, I guess, 16 megabytes.

What is the absolute fastest way to do this? What are the subsequent speed bottlenecks that I don't know about? What changes when you have N pairs of input files (but still only one output)?

Note: I know this is going to be processor-dependent, but at this point I don't know enough to ask questions on processor-dependent things.

PS - Bonus points if you can recommend what tools, environment, etc, are necessary to start working with this, and on this level.

PPS - Tag away! I don't know enough to know what else with which to tag this question.

Comment: While `assembly` will get you to the bare CPU essentials, which sometimes equates to speed, as you appear to be starting with nothing you should probably look for File utilities or Extract Transfer Load (ETL) type tools as it probably has been written before.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @FrankC., but those do not appear to be anything like what I'm after. Can you elaborate on why you think those will help?

Comment: The major factor here is, whether you have to read the files from disk/network, or they are already in memory. If you have to read them, then just write the most naive loop (pretty much what you have in question) in C++ (or basically anything, maybe even javascript would be faster than the disk I/O, although I'm in doubt, the C/C++/Java/C# are safe) and optimize the file read/write part to use reasonably sized buffers plus the fastest available OS API for reading/writing files. As that will take so much time, that even unoptimized loop will then process the data in a fraction of I/O time.

Comment: If those data are already in memory (for example some other process is producing them on the same machine), then it makes sense to work a bit on the processing code. Still a lean simple C++ implementation with properly designed data structures (nurturing cache lines) and fast I/O calls, without any specific tricks, will be probably so close to optimal solution, that you would need serious budget/effort to achieve something reasonably better (in terms of improvement/cost ratio). *"What are the subsequent speed bottlenecks"* => you will never know without profiling some initial version.

Comment: What architecture do you want to use for this?

Comment: A good C or C++ compiler should be able to auto-vectorize that expression with a compare and blend.  (It can't use packed min or max instructions because the data being selected isn't the data being compared).  Agreed with @Ped7g that choosing an I/O block size is important.  Small enough that A1 is still in L2 or L3 cache by the time you're done reading B2.  Big enough that you don't do too many read() calls.

Comment: @PeterCordes that min/max comment made me thinking... so packing A1+A2 data into word pairs as A1aA2aA1bA2b... and doing the same with B, would allow to use min on words, then unpack only second bytes into result. I'm sort of suspicious that in the end it would perform almost the same to the compare-mask-blend variant (as it will be probably capped at memory throughput), but only profiling would tell the truth... :) (edit: the word min variant does produce unstable results when A1==B1 (then min(A2,B2) wins))

Comment: @Ped7g: huh, yeah that's an interesting idea.  But SSE doesn't have very convenient pack instructions.  To use PACKUSWB on two consecutive PMINUW results to get one packed vector of results for C[], you'd have to zero the upper half of each word element for both PMINUW results separately, with PAND.  So for each vector of C[], you need 4 loads, 2x PMINUW, 2x PAND, 1x PACKUSWB (5 total ALU uops).  Compare that with 4 loads, 1x PCMPGTB, 1x PBLENDVB.  Variable blends are only 2 uops on Haswell.  I think you'd only use the PMIN method if you *wanted* the results zero-extended / unpacked.

Comment: @Ped7g: Of course, for 32-bit elements, you can pick just the even elements from 2 vectors with SHUFPS.  On SnB-family, it doesn't even have any bypass delay when used between integer instructions.

Answer (score 2):

On modern x86 CPU the fastest way would be very likely a variation on SIMD instructions:

- read A1, B1 pack of bytes into 2 registers.
- read A2, B2 pack of bytes into other 2 registers
- compare A1, B1 to produce byte mask like 00FF00FFFF00... marking which A1 bytes were smaller.
- clean A2 by the mask (bitwise `and`)
- invert the mask (so now it marks wanted bytes from B2)
- clean B2 by the mask
- `or` modified A2+B2 together and write it into result buffer.
- loop.

How many packed bytes you will be able to process at the same time depends on your target x86 (which SIMD instruction it does support). The latest ones would be maybe able to process this in 512b chunks (64 bytes), although I didn't study particular instructions, so not sure whether the required byte-packed compare/and/or/xor are available for those.

Anyway, this is IMO purely theoretical exercise, as the disk/network I/O will be so slow, that any code looping over single bytes would be able to starve the I/O queues.

So there's no point to bother with the processing loop that much, just make sure your buffer sizes make some sense, and that you don't do something stupid like copying bytes back and forth (common thing mostly in non C/C++ languages, where less experienced programmers have no idea how the data are structured in memory, and they toss them around left/right with several useless conversions just to get "something working").

The I/O part of code will be decisive for overall performance.

Second factor will be cache-usage (cache friendliness of data structures).

The code of loop will be negligible compared to these two, the total time of processing will probably not change, just power usage of CPU, as it will idle more with optimized code.

Comment: Oh, now I see you are talking only about small 16MiB files, hm... well, the code may affect total runtime a bit, but still IMO the biggest part of it will be I/O of OS of reading 2x 16MiB and writing 1x 16MiB. If you would work over some large files, then the cost of code would be covered completely by waiting for I/O.

Comment: Fantastic! Files will be in memory definitely; although atm I don't know enough for that to mean more than "in RAM". Does it make a difference doing this on the CPU or GPU, at least from the processing perspective? Can you tell me more about cache-friendliness?

Comment: With SSE4.1, you can use [PBLENDVB](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PBLENDVB.html) to replace the PANDN / PAND / POR step.  It's slightly more efficient.  AVX2 has 256b integer vectors.  AVX512f doesn't have byte-element compares, so you'd need AVX512BW.  (I think the only currently-available AVX512f hardware (Knight's Landing Xeon Phi) does not have that.)  But if your elements are 32-bit integers, I think you're all set for KNL.  AVX512 compares are neat: the destination is a mask register, and you can then use the mask with later instructions.  A blend is just a masked MOVDQA.

Comment: @Narfanator 16MiB should be enough to split between CPUs and GPUs for parallel processing, but that will starve the I/O even faster, so it makes sense probably only if the CPU does also generate those files in memory in other application. Cache-friendliness ... for A/B only you can read the files as is. For A/B/C/... it would be probably better to interleave the data to fit all related "1" and "2" inside few memory pages like 4-64k, so during single loop you will not run out of cache lines. Anyway, I think you are sort of over-engineering it, build first (simple) version first, then profile.

Comment: Fantastic advice, folks, thanks! I have a lot of reading to do. I suspect that the initial files will actually be GPU generated, in which case it sounds like I'd want to do the processing on the GPU.